# Getting "You're almost there!" on new 8th wall project?

Tags: aframe, 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I'm seeing "You're almost there!" message on a new 8th wall project, however I'm using Google Chrome on the device.

Here's the project code on Glitch:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/humble-harpymimus?path=index.html:15:125

Here's the 8th wall project unique ID:
https://www.8thwall.com/jsxbpchh/glitchtesting

Attached is a screenshot from the mobile phone
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot the URL being displayed is "http://humble-harpymimus.glitch.me", note the **http**. Make sure you are connecting via **https** - this is required by browsers for camera access.

Comment: Yes that was it! Problem fixed